# Удаление файла в c++

Tags: c++, файлы

Файл заранее не известен(название), название хранится в переменной "*a*" **типа string**, например text.txt :

```
string a;
getline(cin, a);
```

тут мы должны удалить этот файл.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove

Comment: там const char мне же нужно с типом string, если я ошибаюсь в чем-то поправьте.

Comment: У `std::string` есть метод для получения c-style строки.

Comment: `remove(a.c_str())`

Answer (score 1):

в С++ 17 появился [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).
Пример с сайта

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    fs::path dir = fs::temp_directory_path();
    fs::create_directories(dir / "abcdef/example");
    std::uintmax_t n = fs::remove_all(dir / "abcdef");
    std::cout << "Deleted " << n << " files or directories\n";
}
```